# .net 7 dependency injection, Mulltiple implementation of same interface

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, .net-7.0

In my startup.cs I have code like this

```
    services.AddScoped<IFileStorage, DiskFileStorage>();
    service.Add<IImageHandler, ImageHandler>();


public class ImageHandler
{
   ImageHandler(IFileStorage fileStorage, ...){}
}
```

now I want to add another class, OtherHandler, that takes a IFileStorage interface, but with another implementation, something like this

```
services.AddScoped<IFileStorage, NetworkFileStorage>();
```

```
public class OtherHandler:IOtherHandler
{
   OtherHandler(IFileStorage, fileStorage)

}
```

Now how do i configure stuff so that the OtherHandler would use the NetworkFileStorage implementation for IFileStorage and anything else would use a default DiskFileStorage implementation?

Update:

Thanks to gunr2171 comment, I discovered that I could do a

`services.AddScoped<IOtherHandler>(provider => new OtherHandler(provider.GetRequiredService<NetworkFileStorage>()));` to get a specific implementation. But still curious if it is possible if I for some reason wanted to use an interface.

Comment: If your handlers have a hard dependency on the specific concrete implementations, why use interfaces at all?

Comment: Not a direct answer but have you considered creating a IFileStorage / INetworkfileStorage interfaces (inheriting from IStorage)  and have your handlers use the appropriate interface ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment @gunr2171, this made me realize that I could get a specific implementation by doing

services.AddScoped<IOtherHandler>(provider =>
new OtherHandler(provider.GetRequiredService<NetworkFileStorage>())); to get a specific implementaiton. But still curious if it is possible if I for some reason wanted to use an interface.

Comment: What do you mean by "if it is possible if I...wanted to use an interface?" You can still use an interface in your OtherHandler code, so the only reference to `NetworkFileStorage` at this point is in your DI binding. Are you envisioning some way for the DI framework to intuit that it should use NetworkFileStorage in certain cases without your configuring it that way?

Answer (score 2):

So, based on my understanding this is your scenario:

```
public interface IFileStorage
{
}

public class NetworkFileStorage: IFileStorage 
{
}

public class DiskFileStorage: IFileStorage 
{
}
```

You also have a couple of services depending on the `IFileStorage` service:

```
public class ImageHandler: IImageHandler
{
  public ImageHandler(IFileStorage fileStorage)
  {
  }
}

public class OtherHandler: IOtherHandler
{
  public OtherHandler(IFileStorage fileStorage)
  {
  }
}
```

You want to register your services so that both of the followings hold true:

- instances of `ImageHandler` are built by injecting `NetworkFileStorage`
- instances of `OtherHandler` are built by injecting `DiskFileStorage`

For simplicity, I'll suppose that all the involved types are implemented so that it is ok to register them as singletons. This depends on the actual implementation, in any case the pattern that I'm going to show you doesn't depend on the actual lifetime of the involved types.

First of all, register the **concrete implementations** of the `IFileStorage` interface. You need to register the classes (**not** the interface): the purpose of this is making sure that the DI container knows these types and it is able to provide you instances of both types.

```
services.AddSingleton<NetworkFileStorage>();
services.AddSingleton<DiskFileStorage>();
```

Now, you can register an implementation for the `IImageHandler` service.
You will use the `ImageHandler` class as the implementing type and you will also provide a factory method to the DI container: by doing so, you are able to select the implementation of `IFileStorage` to be injected (in this case you will select the `NetworkFileStorage` type).

```
services.AddSingleton<IImageHandler>(sp => 
{
  var fileStorage = sp.GetRequiredService<NetworkFileStorage>();
  return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<ImageHandler>(sp, fileStorage);
});
```

You can do a similar thing to register the `OtherHandler` class as the implementation for the `IOtherHandler` service, and select the class `DiskFileStorage` as the type being injected in the constructor of `OtherHandler`:

```
services.AddSingleton<IOtherHandler>(sp => 
{
  var fileStorage = sp.GetRequiredService<DiskFileStorage>();
  return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<OtherHandler>(sp, fileStorage);
});
```

Let me add a final note on your design. There is something wrong with it.
It seems to me that the `ImageHandler` class is somewhat strongly coupled with the `NetworkFileStorage` class, while the `OtherHandler` class is somewhat strongly coupled with the `DiskFileStorage` class.

I would expect both of these classes to work fine with **any** implementation of the `IFileStorage` interface. If these classes do really depend only on the **behavior** described by the `IFileStorage` interface, then any actual implementation of that behavior should be fine for them to work as expected. This is basically a violation of the *Liskov Substitution Principle*.

If this is not the case, maybe the interface `IFileStorage` is not a useful abstraction for your domain model and you should considered to redesign it or to define two different interfaces (one suited to the needs of the `ImageHandler` class and the other suited to the needs of the `OtherHandler` class).

Answer (score 1):

I think there might be a more flexible approach here. It uses `Adapter` pattern for your services, allowing you to stay away from registering concrete implementations, and doesn't force you to instantiate every type manually that uses some `FileStorage` implementation.

```
// A generic storage that can be used for any scenario
    public interface IFileStorage<T> where T : IFileAdapter
    {
        protected T Adapter { get; }

        Task Handle();
    }

    // a base interface that defines the shape of adapter
    public interface IFileAdapter
    {
        Task Handle();
    }

    // copy interfaces to separate the services
    public interface ILocalFileAdapter : IFileAdapter
    {
    }

    public interface IRemoteFileAdapter : IFileAdapter
    {
    }

    // specific implementations
    public class RemoteFileAdapter : IRemoteFileAdapter
    {
        private readonly ILogger<RemoteFileAdapter> logger;

        public RemoteFileAdapter(ILogger<RemoteFileAdapter> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public Task Handle()
        {
            this.logger.LogWarning("Handling file remotely");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    public class LocalFileAdapter : ILocalFileAdapter
    {
        private readonly ILogger<LocalFileAdapter> logger;

        public LocalFileAdapter(ILogger<LocalFileAdapter> logger)
        {
            this.logger = logger;
        }

        public Task Handle()
        {
            this.logger.LogWarning("Handling file locally");

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
    }

    // generic storage that uses an adapter to handle the scenario
    public class FileStorage<T> : IFileStorage<T> where T : IFileAdapter
    {
        public FileStorage(T fileAdapter)
        {
            Adapter = fileAdapter;
        }

        public T Adapter { get; }

        public Task Handle()
        {
            return this.Adapter.Handle();
        }
    }
```

Register your services like below :

```
  builder.Services.AddSingleton<ILocalFileAdapter, LocalFileAdapter>();
  builder.Services.AddSingleton<IRemoteFileAdapter, RemoteFileAdapter>();
  // aspnet.core allows you to register generic services
  builder.Services.AddSingleton(typeof(IFileStorage<>), typeof(FileStorage<>));
```

And this is how you use your `IFileStorageService`:

```
 public WeatherForecastController(IFileStorage<ILocalFileAdapter> localFileStorage, IFileStorage<IRemoteFileAdapter> remoteFileStorage)
 {
     localFileStorage.Handle();
     remoteFileStorage.Handle();
 }
// which will log :
// Handling file locally
// Handling file remotely
```